# Downloading "unknown" file from Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

If I try to download the GoogleService-info.plist file from Firebase console, I download a file named "unknown".

This is not the first project in which I use firebase but this time I have found this problem. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this problem recently as well. It seems like a bug in Firebase. The good news is, it's simple to fix.

The contents of the file seems to be ok. I think it's only the file name that's been messed up. That's why I just renamed the file to `GoogleService-Info.plist` and dragged it to the project as usual. And it works perfectly fine!